# How to get input field text and display on label immediately using php/jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For example: user enter abc on input field, the label will show abc immediately without click any button.

```
<input type="text" value="abc"/>
<label>abc</label>
```

Comment: [onChange()](http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=823)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML :

```
<input type="text" value="abc" id="text1"/>
<label id="label1">abc</label>
```

Jquery :

Use `keyup` as shown :-

```
$("#text1").keyup(function(){
   $("#label1").text($(this).val());   //OR $("#label1").html($(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/5pdh6300/1/

**Edit :-**

A good link to read more about `keyup` event :- http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onChange()` event of jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: `change` event doesn't belong to jQuery, you can use `on` or `change` method for _listening_ to the event.

Comment: can you give example of `onchange`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
  $('label').text($(this).val());
})
```

More correctly:

```
$('input#id').on('change',function(){
  $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').text($(this).val());
})
```

And your html should be:

```
<input type="text" value="abc" id="id"/>
<label for="id">abc</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $('label').html($(this).val());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pybap3u/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create this using `keyup(function(){}` function of jQuery.

**Follow this - [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/JV2qW/2/) for source code**

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="text" value="abc" id="input"/>
<label id="label1">abc</label>
```

Jquery

```
$("#input").keyup(function(){
$("#label1").html($(this).val());
});
```